# Call Method Using Variable

Tags: android

I am developing a quiz, I would like to call the following method using the question number as a variable:

```
private void question2() {
    ....
}
```

So instead of calling this way:

```
question2();
```

I would like to call this way:

```
question+number(); (where number is defined as string "2")
```

I tried:

```
Method method = MyClassName.class.getDeclaredMethod("question" + number);
method.invoke();
```

But get error:

```
The method invoke(Object, Object...) in the type Method is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `question(int)` method which takes a `int` parameter which is the question number ,and then inside the definition of your `question(int)` just check which question number has arrived and take appropriate action.

Comment: Along with what Parag Kadam said above, using a switch statement inside the `question()` method would make your sorting very easy and clean.

Comment: I am doing a complex quiz, if the user answers question 3 it does not necessarily mean that the next question is 4, it could be 15 depending on the answer selected, if I use methods I feel more in control

Comment: what is your logic to determine which question will be selected next?

Comment: @user5174952 - What you are describing is exactly the solution Parag demonstrated below in his answer. Complete control over which question to present based on a number that is returned by the user's selection...

Comment: No @NoChinDeluxe , the OP just said that the next question to be selected is based on the answer of the previous question and not based on the question number of the current question. Hence I am asking him the logic he uses to determine the next question so that I can provide a precise solution.

Comment: thank you for your help, however a precise solution for me would be calling the method " methodGREEN(); " using the variable "String color = GREEN" such as " method+color(); "

Comment: @ParagKadam - I don't see a difference there. You're still passing in an argument into the quesiton method and then testing the argument to decide what to do next. That's the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes you are right I have not updated the answer since the OP did not tell me the logic of how the next question is determined.

Answer (score 0):

```
void question(int questionNumber)
{

   switch(questionNumber)
   case 1: // Do what you want to do for question 1
           break;
   case 2: // Do what you want to do for question 2
           break;
}
```

This is the right approach to your problem.